# Unable to track changes to Mail folders using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I requested for a solution for the below query last month. But i haven't received any solution for this. Please someone help me out with this.

am using graph api to synchronize user's mails and mail folders to the application. Earlier the application uses EWS for synchronization. So when the scheduler runs, the console application will fetch the data using EWS and save it to the database. When using EWS, the code tracks the changes based on changetype like this

```
ChangeCollection\<FolderChange\> fcc = service.ExchangeService.SyncFolderHierarchy(GetFolderId("MsgFolderRoot"), PropertySet.IdOnly, service.EmailRootSyncState);

foreach (FolderChange fc in fcc)
{
switch (fc.ChangeType)
{
case ChangeType.Create:
break;
case ChangeType.Delete:
break;
case ChangeType.Update:
break
}
}
```

So now, using graph api, am trying to retrieve the deleted and renamed (updated) folders like this

Full code goes here...

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var tenantId = "some tenantId";
    var clientId = "some clientid";
    var clientSecret = "some client secret";
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default;

    var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(
        tenantId,
        clientId,
        clientSecret,
        new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud });

    GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(credentials);
    var users = await _graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();

    
    string FolderQueryODataDeltaLink = "previous delta token;

    var folderqueryOptions = new List<Option> { };
    if (FolderQueryODataDeltaLink != "")
    {
        folderqueryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$deltatoken", FolderQueryODataDeltaLink));
        folderqueryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("changeType", "deleted"));
    }

    var folders = await _graphServiceClient.Users[userid]
                            .MailFolders
                            .Delta()
                            .Request(folderqueryOptions)
                            .GetAsync();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

But i get all the changed ones (Both deleted folders and renamed folders). Even if i give the changetype as "created", it brings the same result. I think, the changetype parameter is not considered at all.

I also tried without giving the deltatoken query parameter and just sending the changetype. It doesn't work.

What am i doing wrong ?

Please someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid you can try `await _graphServiceClient.Users[userid].MailFolders.Delta().AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("?changeType=created");` because `changeType` is not odata query parameter.

Comment: var requestBuilder = _graphServiceClient.Users[userid].MailFolders.Delta();
var url = requestBuilder.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("?changeType=deleted");

MailFolderChildFoldersCollectionRequestBuilder builder = new MailFolderChildFoldersCollectionRequestBuilder(url, _graphServiceClient);
var childfolders = await builder.Request().GetAsync();


Tried as per your response, but no luck. am getting all the folder list.